# What is the difference between Build Artifact and Pipeline Artifact tasks?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In Azure DevOps, we have [Download](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops)/[Publish](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops) Build Artifact tasks and [Download](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/download-pipeline-artifact?view=azure-devops)/[Publish](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-pipeline-artifact?view=azure-devops) Pipeline Artifact tasks.

What is the difference between the build artifact tasks and the pipeline artifact tasks and when would we choose one over the other?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

There is an issue about it in [Azure DevOps GitHub](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/issues/2341) and Microsoft answered:

> Hey everyone - I'm from the Azure Artifacts team and we built the
>   Pipeline Artifacts feature that you've discovered in Azure Pipelines.
>
> I'll address the most important comment around documentation - we've
>   got a whole new page coming out around Artifacts in Azure Pipelines
>   which lists out each artifact type that we support and what they are
>   for along with links to specific documentation. We think that should
>   answer most of your questions.
>
> Because that is still being edited before we publish it I thought I
>   would give you the 30,000 foot view on the difference between Pipeline
>   Artifacts and Build Artifacts and also mention how Pipeline Artifacts
>   relate to Universal Packages.
>
> Build Artifacts (published via the Publish Build Artifacts task) have
>   been in Azure DevOps for a long time and are the built-in artifact
>   storage mechanism for Azure Pipelines. Most builds that store
>   non-package artifacts today would likely use this task. The task can
>   push the content up to the server/cloud but can also copy the files to
>   a local file share.
>
> Pipeline Artifacts (published using the Publish Pipeline Artifact task
>   are intended as the replacement for Build Artifacts. They are in
>   preview right now and there are a few more things we need to do to
>   reach parity. The benefit of Pipeline Artifacts is that they can
>   dramatically reduce the time it takes to upload and download large
>   artifacts. We do this be first checking whether the content that is
>   being uploaded exists in the service. We do this not just at the
>   per-file level but also at the sub-file level (in up to 128K chunks).
>   It can lead to really dramatic performance improvements.
>
> Universal Packages - also in preview use the same storage/transfer
>   technology as Pipeline Artifacts. You would use Universal Packages
>   when you want to create an artifact with a life time independent of
>   the pipeline that created it. You can download Pipeline Artifacts
>   after a pipeline has completed via the artifacts UX - but if you want
>   something that really exists independent of pipeline you would go for
>   Universal Packages. There should be no performance difference between
>   the two.
>
> Hopefully this helps. Feel free to ask any more questions and I'll
>   follow-up with answers.

Comment: please update with `we've got a whole new page coming out`

Comment: @BozoJoe it's probably this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/artifacts-overview?view=azure-devops